# Are there only finitely many distinct cubic walk-regular graphs that are neither vertex-transitive nor distance-regular?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

The class of walk-regular graphs contains the vertex-transitive graphs and the distance-regular graphs. However, there are walk-regular graphs that are neither vertex-transitive nor distance-regular. In particular, I believe that I found a first example of a cubic walk-regular graph that is neither vertex-transitive nor distance-regular on 20 vertices: its *Graph6* code is `SsP@@?OC?S@C@_@C?K?A_?AG?D??C_??]`.

My question here is: are there only finitely many cubic walk-regular graphs (up to isomorphism) that are neither vertex-transitive nor distance-regular *(or is it e.g. possible to construct an infinite family of graphs of this kind)*?

*There are e.g. only finitely many distinct cubic distance-regular graphs  - could it e.g. also be true that there are only finitely many distinct non-vertex-transitive cubic walk-regular graphs?*

Comment: I expect you mean "connected finite graph" when you say "graph"?

Comment: Yeah, what I'm really implicitly meaning with my question(s) is *connected finite simple graph*, I suppose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A graph is called semisymmetric if it is regular, edge-transitive but not vertex-transitive.

Semisymmetric graphs are walk-regular hence they provide example of graphs that are regular and walk-regular but not vertex-transitive.

This answers your question, as it is known that there are infinitely many semisymmetric cubic graphs (I could probably dig up a reference for this if you need), and, as you note, only finitely many of these can be distance-regular.

Krystal Guo and I noticed this last year (and even e-mailed Brendan about it) but deemed it too minor to write it up.

Comment: Semisymmetric graphs are walk regular.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, Yes I had completely forgotten your correspondence from last September.  Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this may answer my question, but perhaps still leaves me with another question: are there only finitely many distinct cubic walk-regular graphs that are neither vertex-transitive, edge-transitive, nor distance-regular?

Comment: More generally, I'd perhaps wonder if some kind of structural characterization of (cubic) walk-regular graphs is possible?

Comment: @m4farrel I don't know the answer to your other question. (The less symmetry involved, the less I know.) If I had to guess, I would say yes. As for a structual characterisation, I don't know, but since that class includes all vertex-transitive and edge-transitive graphs, that seems a bit unlikely?

Comment: The families of walk-regular graphs that I know of (now) are the vertex-transitive graphs, the semi-symmetric graph (as you've mentioned), the distance-regular graphs, regular triangle-free connected graphs with at most six distinct eigenvalues, regular bipartite connected graphs with at most five distinct eigenvalues, and regular connected graphs with at most four distinct eigenvalues. Is it possible find a true statement along the lines of a graph is e.g. walk-regular if and only if it is one of the kinds of graphs I just mentioned or if it is X, Y, or Z?

Comment: I  think that none the graphs listed in my answer is semisymmetric.  The six graphs have respectively 2,6,3,5,5,5 orbits of edges.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Hi Chris. I've heard that you've got a very nice proof of this fact. Would you mind posting it?

Comment: A question that I find interesting: are there any walk-regular graphs with a trivial automorphism group?

Comment: @m4farrel I don't think that there is any chance that there is a classification of the type you are seeking, but this is just working from general principles about how graphs, groups and spectra interrelate, and I don't think I can make a more precise statement.

Comment: I didn't write a proof, but I'm confident that you also get a walk-regular graph if you replace each vertex of a semisymmetric (or symmetric) cubic graph by a triangle.  Or a clique of size $k$ for a $k$-regular semisymmetric graph.  I tried it for the Gray graph and got a walk-regular non-semisymmetric cubic graph with 162 vertices.  This operation does not work  for all walk-regular cubic graphs.

Comment: We also had an operation that yielded regular walk-regular non-semisymmetric graphs starting from semisymmetric ones. I can't remember what it is at the moment, but I think it involved cartesian products. Using it, we were able to answer the OP's question for every valency $d\geq 3$. (That is, find infinitely many $d$-valent walk-regular non-vertex-transitive graphs.)

Comment: The cartesian product of two copies of the Gray graph gives a walk-regular 6-valent graph on 2916 vertices with 3 orbits.

Comment: @m4farrel If you are happy with the answer, you should accept it, so it disappears from the unanswered queue.

Comment: @verret Oh, I'm relatively unfamiliar with StackExchange - I'm not even sure whose answer would be most appropriate to formally Accept in this instance, since I think most of the answers (and even the comments here) have been valuable?

Answer (score 6):

This is a good question and I'm fairly sure the answer is not known. My collection of non-transitive cubic connected walk-regular graphs looks like this:

```
  1 graphs : n=20; girth=6; bipartite; radius=4; diameter=5; orbits=2
  1 graphs : n=30; girth=6; bipartite; radius=5; diameter=5; orbits=3
  1 graphs : n=32; girth=6; bipartite; radius=5; diameter=6; orbits=2
  1 graphs : n=60; girth=3; not bipartite; radius=8; diameter=10; orbits=3
  1 graphs : n=1200; girth=3; not bipartite; radius=19; diameter=20; orbits=3
  1 graphs : n=3600; girth=3; not bipartite; radius=22; diameter=22; orbits=3
```

I've had them for several years but never got around to publishing them.

The list is complete up to 30 vertices, and for 32 vertices it is complete for triangle-free cubic graphs.

Comment: Is your list known to be complete up to any number of vertices?

Comment: @GordonRoyle : added

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you happen to have e.g. _Graph6_ codes for your examples here, so that I can e.g. have a closer look at these graphs and their properties?

Comment: @m4farrel Sure, just send me email.  brendan.mckay AT anu.edu.au .

Comment: Also, I think that it may be worth mentioning that every regular triangle-free connected graph with at most six distinct eigenvalues is walk-regular - and, in particular, the the first example on 20 vertices that I found falls into this family of walk-regular graphs (it is triangle-free with { +/- 1, +/- 2, +/- 3} as its set of eigenvalues).

Comment: It is also the case that every regular bipartite  connected graph with at most five distinct eigenvalues is walk-regular and likewise that every regular connected graph with at most four distinct eigenvalues is walk-regular - I'd wonder if your examples here might also e.g. fall into some of the families of walk-regular graphs that I've mentioned here?

Comment: So a graph with diameter $d$ has at least $d+1$ distinct eigenvalues, so fixing the valency at 3 and the number of eigenvalues at 4/5/6 can only give finitely many examples. Also, btw, the 54-vertex Gray graph is apparently the smallest cubic semisymmetric graph..

Comment: @GordonRoyle Right, so who has a machine-readable catalogue?

Comment: Marston and Primoz have constructed all semi-symmetric cubic graphs on up to 10000 vertices, but I can't actually find the catalogue at the moment (haven't looked hard enough).

Comment: For a reference up to 768, see this : link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10801-006-7397-3 This is not machine-readable though. I just asked Marston and he confirmed that their latest computation (from 2012) is up to 10000. They've never made it publicly available, but it's available "on request". It's machine-readable, but it may require a bit of work. (They give some relations to generate a normal subgroup of one of the Goldschmidt amalgam, the wanted graph is a coset graph of the corresponding quotient.)

Comment: @GordonRoyle Oh, thanks. After thinking about it for a minute, I think now that there must not be any non-vertex-transitive non-distance-regular cubic walk-regular graphs that belong to the second two families of graphs that I mentioned? I also wonder if Brendan McKay's example here on 30 is triangle-free graph with six distinct eigenvalues, and also what families (if any) of walk-regular graphs the example on 32 vertices could then possibly fall into?

Answer (score 6):

What follows is a proof that semisymmetric graphs are walk-regular.

Say vertices $u$ and $v$ in a graph $X$ are *cospectral* if the graphs $X\setminus u$ and $X\setminus v$ are cospectral. If $X$ is semisymmetric, then the vertices in each colour class are cospectral. Two vertices $u$ and $v$ in a bipartite graph are cospectral if, for each non-negative integer $k$, the number of closed walks of length $2k$ starting at $u$ equals the number starting at $v$. [This is proved, for example, in Section 8.13 in one of my favourite texts on algebraic graph theory. :-)]

The adjacency matrix $A$ of any bipartite graph can be written in the form
\[
  A =\begin{pmatrix}0&B\\ B^T&0\end{pmatrix}
\]
and hence
\[ 
  A^{2k} = \begin{pmatrix}(BB^T)^k&0\\ 0&(B^TB)^k&\end{pmatrix}
\]
Since $X$ is semisymmetric, the diagonal entries of $(BB^T)^k$ are all equal, as are the diagonal entries of $(B^TB)^k$.

By the cyclic symmetry of trace, we see that $(BB^T)^k$ and $(B^TB)^k$ have the same trace. Therefore the diagonal entries of these two matrices are equal, and it follows that $X$ is walk regular.